# Custom scrollbar for div loaded through AJAX --- Scrolling DIVs for tablets

Tags: ipad, html, scroll, scrollbar

Two different but related questions.

1) How can I create a simple custom scrollbar for a div that is loaded via AJAX?

I used this tutorial: http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar and I can get it to work for a div that with the same properties but not once I integrate it to the page with the AJAX function. The site itself mentions flexscroll can be used for divs that load content dynamically but I don't quite understand how.

2) How can I make a div scrollable in Apple / Android tablets? Any recommended tutorials for this?

Thanks in advance.